# Bootstrap Rows and Columns - Do I need to use row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I just need clarification with a certain point in Bootstrap Grid's rows and columns..
On this link: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid; the 3rd point under Introduction says: 
"Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows."

What exactly does this mean?
What I am trying to do is put 2 columns: col-xs-4, col-xs-8; inside col-xs-12 which is itself inside a row. Will this work..

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-4">some content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">some other content</div>
</div>
```

Or will I have to insert a new(and nested..i suppose) row inside xol-xs-12 and then the other 2 cols in that row ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2022)**

Technically `row` isn't *required* in Bootstrap 5 since [columns can be used standalone](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#standalone-column-classes) to set width, However, `row` is still needed for the flexbox [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/) which is primary how columns are used.

---

**Bootstrap 3, Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

> Bootstrap Rows and Columns - Do I need to use row?

### Yes, you *need* to use row.

---

**Update 2018**

The `row`>`col` relationship is the same in both **Bootstrap 3 and 4** in that..

## "only columns may be immediate children of rows"

So, the nested columns (`.col-*`) *must* also be inside a `.row`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4">some content</div>
       <div class="col-xs-8">some other content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As [you can see here](https://codeply.com/go/TnszJLLsg4) you should always use the `row`. This is *very* important in **Bootstrap 4** because the columns will **simply stack (wrap) vertically** if not placed inside a  `.row`. The `.row` has a negative margin of 15px on either side, so the benefit is that..

- 100% width content inside `container`
- separate content into rows (force cols to be on line)
- nest the grid row>col and maintain alignment on outer sides

---

From the [Bootstrap 3 Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)...

> Content should be placed within columns, and **only columns may be
> immediate children of rows**.

From the [Bootstrap 4 Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works)...

> Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
> (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding
> is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all
> the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side... content  must be placed within columns and **only columns may be immediate children of
> rows**.

---

https://medium.com/wdstack/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works-471d7a089cfc

Comment: thanks you for your answer, and especially the links!
I now see the difference between using the inner row vs not using it, is that it affects the 15px margin of content :)
So far i was thinking that it should break the markup and not work if the inner row was omitted.

Comment: So, whats a row-col ? Can you explain it with material ui components? I understand row is grid container and col is grid item so far.

Comment: row-col is new for Bootstrap 4.2+ and Bootstrap 5. It simplifies the markup since it only requires adding a CSS class to the row, instead of all columns inside the row.

Answer (score 11):

### 2021 Update

No, you no longer need rows.  From the [Bootstrap 5.0 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#standalone-column-classes):

> The .col-* classes can also be used outside a .row to give an element
> a specific width. Whenever column classes are used as non direct
> children of a row, the paddings are omitted.

Answer (score 2):

You should have parent `<div class="row">` for using `<div class="col-*>`

something like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">some content</div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">some other content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now in the above code if i remove the 2nd row div.. and have col-xs-4 & col-xs-8 directly under col-xs-12 then also it works without any issue. that's the thing i am WONDERING about? it shouldn't work if i go by the documentation but it does!

Comment: @RahulPatwa for that you need to **nest** http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 1):

Always use the following pattern:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6"> some content </div>
          <div class="col-md-6"> another content </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Always use row class inside col and container class , never use col inside col class and never directly use col class inside container class