# What is the use of class="container" attribute inside <div> tag in bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have seen many pages having class="container" inside div tag, but what is the use of it? As per what I understand div tag itself is a container then what is the purpose of class="container"?

Comment: For reference, see [Containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#containers). Also see [About Bootstrap Grid system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39269515/924299) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43172619/924299).

Answer (score 4):

You're right in saying that div is a container itself. But, frameworks like Bootstrap have defined their CSS in such a way that you will find different classes everywhere.
The container class can be applied to an element other than div too, although div is recommended.

The container class gives your webpage some basic margins and sets it in a way that it is easy to view on all devices.

This is specific to Bootstrap. Other frameworks may use the same name "container" or something else for the same purpose.

Comment: Got the point. Out of curiosity, using a form inside a div makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

actually "container" class contains its own styling that is written in bootstrap class like div is just empty container but "container" class has, for example, 1000px width and also some media queries for mobile-friendly usage responsive designing.
the empty div tag does not equal to "container" class.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing I am learning Flexbox and I was watching a tutorial and they had a div with a class container that they added to every section and put a width, margin and padding on it. I was wondering if I should be adding a container class every time I make a website

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35643941)