# Wrapping bootstrap columns in extra div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap v4 and when I wrap columns in extra div the layout becomes broken. Why is that? Link to codepen http://codepen.io/mariuszdaniel/pen/aJJjzJ

Works

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not working

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="myclass">
            <div class="col-4"></div>
            <div class="col-8"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because `col-*` ***must*** be placed *directly* inside `row`.

Read the [Bootstrap docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#how-it-works)..

> "Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows."

This is *especially* important in **Bootstrap 4** because the columns will simply stack/wrap vertically if not placed ***directly*** inside a  `.row`.

---

**Also read**:

[How the Bootstrap Grid Works](https://medium.com/wdstack/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works-471d7a089cfc)
[Bootstrap Rows and Columns - Do I need to use row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053195/bootstrap-rows-and-columns-do-i-need-to-use-row)
[Bootstrap 4.0 Grid System Layout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521269/bootstrap-4-0-grid-system-layout-not-working/45521495)

Comment: Thanks. I must have overlooked this somehow.

Comment: Is there a workaround? I need to have this extra div, but I want bootstrap to "ignore" it.