# Bootstrap 4.0 Grid System Layout not working

Tags: layout, grid, row, bootstrap-4, col

I'm trying to do a layout with bootstrap, but I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong. I'm putting two columns of 6 and the second column of 6 I'm putting 2 columns of 3 inside, but it's not working. I'm new to bootstrap.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
   <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1" style="border-right: solid 1px #ffbfbf;border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">a</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;"><div style="height: 700px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a a a a a a</div></div>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left:0px;border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;"><div style="height: 320px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a</div></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left:0px;border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;"><div style="height: 320px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a</div></div>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left:0px;border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;"><div style="height: 320px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a</div></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left:0px;border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;"><div style="height: 320px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a</div></div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
335
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do :

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're just missing a basic Bootstrap "rule". From the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works)..

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and ***only***
>   columns may be ***immediate children of rows***.

In **Bootstrap 4**, `.col-` that are ***not*** placed in `.row` **will stack vertically**.

https://www.codeply.com/go/GlA3IP7oGU

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">
        <div style="height: 700px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a a a a a a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left:0px;border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">
                <div style="height: 320px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left:0px;border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">
                <div style="height: 320px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left:0px;border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">
                <div style="height: 320px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left:0px;border-left: solid 1px #ffbfbf;">
                <div style="height: 320px; background-color: #FF3355; border-radius: 15px;">a</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

[Read **how Bootstrap nesting works**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting)

---

Related: [Wrapping bootstrap columns in extra div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723792/wrapping-bootstrap-columns-in-extra-div/42723848)