# Specify Number of Rows and Columns in Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to specify the number of rows and columns in a grid?

My code is giving me 3 columns and 4 rows. I want 4 columns, and 3 rows. Is there way conduct this with CSS and HTML? I'm willing to use Bootstrap also, trying to edit the code below correctly.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) to specify the number of columns.
The number of columns is defined by the number of values in the list.

Below, I'm using [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) as shorthand to generate four values.
Based on your existing code, `auto auto auto auto` would also work.

Also see [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) relies on specifying [both rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053352/924299). The [answer from maik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799364/924299) is a good example.

Comment: cool, i accepted his answer, make sure you give thumbs up, thanks

Answer (score 0):

using Bootstrap 4 - 3 rows x 4 columns

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- row one -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.row -->
  <!-- row two -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.row -->
  <!-- row three -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      content
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.row -->

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Of course you will need to link to Bootstrap CDNs for this to work

Comment: thanks, what if I don't know the number of items in grid, it can be 3,5,9.  do I really have to specify number all 12 items? is there clean code way?

Comment: Not necessary to stipulate the total amount of columns _ If you are creating them dynamically simply ensure that they're individually given the .col class in the dynamic code & within an encompassing .row class and they will sort themselves out according to how many columns there are _ Be sure to maintain rows as required too _ Here's a link to a tutorial that might help _ https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp _ Alternatively you can use the Bootstrap 4 website for more details _ If this answer suits your needs please be sure to click the upvote on the side ; )