# HTML Specify Length and Width of Square Grid Picture System

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a square grid. I would like to make the size of the pictures smaller by specifying measurement, while retaining the 2x2 shape, or 3x3 shape etc. Tried setting the width property but did not work. Currently its too big.
How would I resolve this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 p-0"><img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image" class="w-100 h-100"></div>
    <div class="col-6 p-0"><img src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7" class="w-100 h-100"></div>

    <div class="col-6 p-0"><img src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png" class="w-100 h-100"></div>
    <div class="col-6 p-0"><img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpgColumn" class="w-100 h-100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Even though pictures are smaller , they should touching edge to edge-

For some reason, this is not working
[make images the same size in bootstrap grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379727/make-images-the-same-size-in-bootstrap-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way in CSS, looking for Bootstrap way, using grid-template-columns

**CSS:**

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
    grid-gap: 0em;
    padding: 0px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding:0px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/san-fransisco-768x432.jpg" alt="san francisco">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/london-768x432.jpg" alt="london">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/new-york-768x432.jpg" alt="new york">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/cape-town-768x432.jpg" alt="cape town">
</div>
```

Another helpful site:

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-css-grid-image-gallery-with-blur-effect-and-interaction-media-queries--cms-32287

[HTML Create an Equal Size Square Grid Picture System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802507/html-create-an-equal-size-square-grid-picture-system)

[Specify Number of Rows and Columns in Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799030/specify-number-of-rows-and-columns-in-grid)

[HTML Specify Divider gap measurement in Square Grid Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808212/html-specify-divider-gap-measurement-in-square-grid-picture)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you out?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image" alt="Fruit" style="width:100%;height:400px">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg" alt="Fruit" style="width:100%;height:400px">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png" alt="Book" style="width:100%;height:400px">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpg" alt="Book" style="width:100%;height:400px">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome, and yes I thought you would get the idea, that's why I didn't include the fourth picture. Also if this answered your question would you mind accepting the answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the <div class="container">.

Comment: if I set the width to 200 px, it becomes a rectangle, they should be squares, also a large vertical padding gap between the pictures, the pictures should be touching edge to edge

Comment: setting the height to 100px does not work, only at 400px,  need to be able to adjust images,

Comment: Changed the answer again and this works for me also. Used the div "<div class="row no-gutters">" for the gap

Comment: trying changing the height to 100 px, I want to be able to adjust dimensions

Answer (score 0):

all images should be of same size e.g 512*512px.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 p-0">
                <img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image"
                    class="">
                <img
                    src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7" style="margin-left:-4px;">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: if I did that, which just test, there is still a white space vertical gap, the pictures should be touching edge to edge

Comment: This might help.     <div class="col-md-12 p-0">
        <img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image"
            class="">
        <img src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7"
            style="margin-left:-4px;">
    </div>