# why are the images being pushed down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

in my code, the first two images of the last row are being pushed down please help me push the images back up to where it is supposed to be

PS: I am using bootstrap 3.4.1
PPS: it shouldn't do anything so you don't have to fix that
PPPS: I can fix the mobile and tablet size problem later so don't worry about dat

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2c3e50 !important;
}
nav a {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PH.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hungry Photos</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>The image Gallery</h1>
            <p>A collection of selected pictures from multiple photographers</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981420-87aa9dad1c89?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577988504339-4dc891bdabe9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577990174632-90bfb7da0119?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577949098254-1ad7b1b526eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577915378375-b18d2bd947c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577895752018-7eefa8a5a2dc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577836660968-ef4cc3909bb2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577918285732-0ddce6230a88?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577907796119-7118da053fab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- row collapse -->
    </div> <!-- container collapse -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

it shouldn't do anything so don't try to fix that

Comment: I have added the code. Hope it will help you. If any changes please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the extra row which you have added in between of col-lg-4. and add this css of display: flex in a row class.

Please check. I hope it will solve your problem. If any changes please let me know.

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2c3e50 !important;
}
nav a {
  color: white !important;
}
.row{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PH.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hungry Photos</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>The image Gallery</h1>
            <p>A collection of selected pictures from multiple photographers</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981420-87aa9dad1c89?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577988504339-4dc891bdabe9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577990174632-90bfb7da0119?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577949098254-1ad7b1b526eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577915378375-b18d2bd947c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577895752018-7eefa8a5a2dc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577836660968-ef4cc3909bb2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577918285732-0ddce6230a88?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577907796119-7118da053fab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            
        </div> <!-- row collapse -->
    </div> <!-- container collapse -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent Work.. @Revti Shah

Comment: can you send me a link to explain how it works? (btw it worked!)

Comment: @why_u_wanna_no_me_name I am using the flex concept in CSS. Here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because of different size of images. You have to add same size (width x height) images in you content. Or you can set height using css.

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2c3e50 !important;
}
nav a {
  color: white !important;
}
div.thumbnail a>img, div.thumbnail>img {
    height: 235px;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
       object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PH.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hungry Photos</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>The image Gallery</h1>
            <p>A collection of selected pictures from multiple photographers</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981420-87aa9dad1c89?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577988504339-4dc891bdabe9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577990174632-90bfb7da0119?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577949098254-1ad7b1b526eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577915378375-b18d2bd947c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577895752018-7eefa8a5a2dc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577836660968-ef4cc3909bb2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577918285732-0ddce6230a88?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577907796119-7118da053fab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- row collapse -->
    </div> <!-- container collapse -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is the same

Comment: Check again i edit that.

Comment: I think that the size is irrelevant

Comment: it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each `col` inside `row` so that there is no more then 12 `col` in a `row`. This is how the `bootstrap-grid` structure works.

> As you can see in their official
>   [DOC](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) that if `12
>   cols` complete the next should go to next `row`.

**

> "only columns may be immediate children of rows"

**

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2c3e50 !important;
}
nav a {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PH.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hungry Photos</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>The image Gallery</h1>
            <p>A collection of selected pictures from multiple photographers</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981420-87aa9dad1c89?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577988504339-4dc891bdabe9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577990174632-90bfb7da0119?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577949098254-1ad7b1b526eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577915378375-b18d2bd947c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577895752018-7eefa8a5a2dc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577836660968-ef4cc3909bb2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577918285732-0ddce6230a88?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577907796119-7118da053fab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div> <!-- row collapse -->
    </div> <!-- container collapse -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For more detail [Bootstrap Rows and Columns - Do I need to use row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053195/bootstrap-rows-and-columns-do-i-need-to-use-row)

Answer (score 0):

> Remove`<div class="row">` in Last column... and if u used bootstrap3 u need to add `display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap`; and if u have used bootstrap 4, u need to Link Bootstrap4 CDN Link...
>
> Note :- This answer in only for, your column not for full page..

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2c3e50 !important;
}
nav a {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PH.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hungry Photos</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>The image Gallery</h1>
            <p>A collection of selected pictures from multiple photographers</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981420-87aa9dad1c89?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577988504339-4dc891bdabe9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577990174632-90bfb7da0119?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577949098254-1ad7b1b526eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577915378375-b18d2bd947c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577895752018-7eefa8a5a2dc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577836660968-ef4cc3909bb2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577918285732-0ddce6230a88?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577907796119-7118da053fab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- row collapse -->
    </div> <!-- container collapse -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```